# ¿Cuál puede ser la causa de este error?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Intentando desarrollar una estrategia de inversión utilizando dataframes, me encuentro con el siguiente problema.

```
import pandas
import pandas_datareader as pdr 
import numpy as np

start = "2010-12-30"
end = "2019-10-28"
nom_val = "ibex35"
ticker = "^IBEX"

df = pdr.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start = start, end = end)
df.rename(columns={ "Adj Close":nom_val}, inplace=True)

dfewm = df[[nom_val]].copy()

def create_ewm(dfewm, start, end, window_fast, window_slow) :
    # Doble cruce de medias móviles de 70 y 200 días
    dfewm["windowfast"] = dfewm[nom_val].ewm(window_fast).mean().dropna()
    dfewm["windowlow"] = dfewm[nom_val].ewm(window_slow).mean().dropna()
    # Algoritmo
    # vectorized evaluation of the trading condition/signal generation
    #dfewm["position"] = np.where(dfewm["windowfast"] > dfewm["windowlow"], 1, -1)
    return dfewm

window_fast = 70
window_slow = 200

start = "2010-12-30"
end = "2019-10-28"

dfewm = create_ewm(df_valor, start, end, window_fast, window_slow)
#dfewm[:3]

# Strategy implementatión
dfewm = df_valor[[nom_val]].copy() 
dfewm.reset_index(inplace = True )
dfewm["signal"] = 0
dfewm["position"] = 0

for i in range (0, dfewm.shape[0]):
    if dfewm["signal"][i] == 0 & dfewm["windowfast"][i-1] < dfewm["windowlow"][-1] & dfewm["windowfast"][i] > dfewm["windowlow"][i]:
        dfewm["position"][i] = 1
        dfewm["signal"][i] = 0

    if dfewm["signal"][i] == 1 & dfewm["windowfast"][i-1] > dfewm["windowlow"][-1] & dfewm["windowfast"][i] < dfewm["windowlow"][i]:
        dfewm["position"][i] = 0
        dfewm["signal"][i] = 0
```

Me devuelve el error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3079             try:
-> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'windowfast'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-8398f68741ca> in <module>
     39 
     40 for i in range (0, dfewm.shape[0]):
---> 41     if dfewm["signal"][i] == 0 & dfewm["windowfast"][i-1] < dfewm["windowlow"][-1] & dfewm["windowfast"][i] > dfewm["windowlow"][i]:
     42         dfewm["position"][i] = 1
     43         dfewm["signal"][i] = 0

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3022             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3023                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3024             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3025             if is_integer(indexer):
   3026                 indexer = [indexer]

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:
-> 3082                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3083 
   3084         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 'windowfast'
```

¿Cuál puede ser la causa de este error?. Agradeceré ayuda.

Comment: Seguro que existe la columna `windowfast`?? si estas seguro entonces ponle un `try/except` en el `try` mete todos los `if` y en el `except` pones `print(dfewm); exit()`. Esto te servirá para saber cuando es que se modifica el DF.

Comment: Efectivamente, tu opción funciona pero, además, es cierto que la columna no existía. El error estaba en esta sentencia que quedaría así: dfewm = create_ewm(dfewm, start, end, window_fast, window_slow)